# Canvas strokeRect vs rect and then stroke performance

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm drawing about 80-100 rectangles on a very big canvas.

What's the best way to go about this?

The 2 solutions I have are using `strokeRect()` inside a for loop OR using `beginPath()` before the loop, `rect()` inside it and `stroke()` after it's done.

Obviously they both work, but is there one that performs better than the other?

Comment: That's worth a try on your side, but for 80-100 rects, the difference might be minor. Usually composing a single Path and calling only once stroke or fill is a clear winner with >5000 smaller paths.

Comment: I see. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you